# Ubuntu Server 18.04 LVM Expansion

Tags: partitioning, lvm, disk-management

I recently built an Ubuntu server to run syslog-ng.  At installation I added a second virtual hard drive in VMware.  I used LVM and mounted the second disk as /var (knowing this is where the logs would be held).

I realised I'd made it too small and want to expand the volume from 50G to 100G, but am unable to do so.  From the installation, the 50G disk I mounted at /var has no partitionas on it.  This is because it is dedicated to /dev/vg1/lv-0, which is mounted to /var.

If I try vgextend, it says there is no free space to use.  pvcreate deosnt seem appropriate either.  Every guide I can see online involves creating a new partition on an expanded disk (e.g. if sdb1 & 2 were part of vg1, extend the disk and create a new partiton sdb3 and add it to the vg1).  I can't follow this because there is only sdb, no sdb1 & 2.

I'm sure I'm missing something, can anyone point me to the answer?

See below for disk info:

**df -h**

Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               967M     0  967M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              200M  1.1M  199M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  2.8G  937M  76% /
tmpfs                              997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv--0               49G  547M   46G   2% /var
/dev/sda2                          976M  145M  765M  16% /boot
/dev/loop0                          90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop1                          89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
tmpfs                              200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000

**pvdisplay**

--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <29.00 GiB / not usable 0
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7423
  Free PE               6399
  Allocated PE          1024
  PV UUID               kqoMlf-LMiz-dEch-t10q-a3eP-gBiN-okGlWc

--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               vg1
  PV Size               50.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              12799
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          12799
  PV UUID               jH9TiD-KFmp-Zl0y-dX7R-o0qo-uXgn-eAYexu

**fdisk -l**

Disk /dev/loop0: 89.1 MiB, 93417472 bytes, 182456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 88.5 MiB, 92778496 bytes, 181208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DD7C344B-94EE-41A0-A6F8-0E8E4B6B72F5

Device       Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096  2101247  2097152   1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 62912511 60811264  29G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdb: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/vg1-lv--0: 50 GiB, 53682896896 bytes, 104849408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Comment: --Edit-- I guess I could add a third disk, /dev/sdc and add it to vg1?  Would that work?  I'd rather expand it if posslbe though...